# Invalid column type name length 2350 exceeds max allowed length 2000 hive create table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have been getting the below error while creating a JSON table. How can I increase the column type length while creating the table. the type of the column is struct. Please help

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. 
InvalidObjectException(message:Invalid column type name length 2350 exceeds max allowed length 2000, type struct
```

Comment: Does this do it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193121/read-a-json-file-with-12-nested-level-into-hive-in-azure-hdinsights#48641694

Comment: Thanks Aaron , But I cannot change the hive-site 's properties , Is there any other way to increase the length of the data type instead of changing the hive-site properties

Answer (score 0):

```
set hive.metastore.max.typename.length=10000;
```

You can run this before your create table statement. Note, this will only update the permissions for your session. It doesn't seem to change the permissions permanently.